# Recommended way of returning a reference from a function in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have been using this approach for returning references from functions in C++. However, I suspect that there is better patterns to perform operations like this. Also, I guess that this approach implies in memory leak.

```
class A {};
A& return_instance_of_A(){
    A* result = new A();
    return *result;
}
```

Using shared_ptr would be a better choice?

Comment: Why do you want to return a reference?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code since you're creating the object on the heap. But why can't you return a pointer?

Comment: It does not imply a memory leak, as the leak doesn't happen until the program fails to free the memory.    The memory can still be freed (if that is part of the function-contract).  You could just as easily return a pointer, and the caller could fail to free that.

Comment: Why not simply use `A return_instance_of_A(){ A result; return A; }`?

Comment: In some operator overloading I saw this pattern of returning references, then I was wondering what would be the best approach to implement such signature.

Comment: @Codor Because that would create a new object (copy-contructor) when leaving the function. (If return value optimisation isn't used)

Comment: @abelenky that's why you should use a smart pointer

Comment: @maja The copy will be elided by any reasonable compiler.

Comment: If the implementation as above is used, how would the object created be destroyed?

Comment: @TartanLlama But `A` would need to be at least movable for that, right?

Comment: @BaummitAugen no, return value optimization would take care of that

Comment: @Codor:  Although awkward and unconventional, there is nothing wrong with `delete &myARef;`, which will delete the object referenced... provided it was allocated with `new`.  The problem is that in large-scale projects, many times when you have a reference, you're not 100% sure how it was created.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Yeah, but that's a requirement for returning by value anyway.

Comment: I'm with @Codor on this.  Returning a stack created object by value should be used.

Comment: @TartanLlama For return by value, [yes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19d5959e6c16618e) (also you are wrong, Slava),  for return by reference [not](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57b0de564a1294ec). So there is real difference between this and return by value. The latter does not work for a general `class A`.

Comment: @Codor In this case, I would be returning a local variable, is this not a problem? Also, the copied return issue would not hit performance?

Comment: @RafaelLadeira It would be ok and in practice just as fast if the class you want to return is at least movable. For example, you cannot return streams by value pre-C++11 (and pre-gcc5 because they did not implement that earlier).

Comment: @BaummitAugen I wasn't suggesting that returning by value has the same constraints as by reference, simply that if you decide to return by value, the copy will be elided.

Comment: @RafaelLadeira It is not a problem in the sense that it does not create a potential memory leak. It might hit performance, but the copying might be optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: @TartanLlama I just wanted to point out the additional constraints and that the blanket advice *"Just return by value"* needs to be stated more precisely.

Comment: So, if the return type is movable, it is guaranteed that no performance penalty will be faced, even in the case of a really large object instance being returned?

Comment: Typic C++: It's one of the most trivial things a language can do, and there is still a huge discussion going on. I like it,

Comment: I mean in the case of a copied stack variable returned.

Comment: @RafaelLadeira Not guaranteed as in *"guaranteed by the standard"*, but in the sense that every reasonable compiler and every common compiler will optimize such a simple case. [Further reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

Comment: If the class has both move- and copy-construction, you are guaranteed by the standard to get the (hopefully cheap) move construction btw, even if no RVO takes place.

Comment: @maja I must agree with you, C++ is really interesting and very confusing often. I'm trying to break my bias towards C#, as I need to implement a library in C++ for performance improvement. Thanks everyone for the responses, I think I need to study a little more.

Comment: So @BaummitAugen, what would be the best in your opinion? stack variable or shared_ptr? If the stack is full of large objects, this is a issue, right?

Comment: @RafaelLadeira Return by value if possible. Do not build objects that use much stack space (i.e. like `sizeof(Object)` big, not like `std::vector` big) in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the recommended way of returning a reference from a function?

Syntactically, just return a reference.

```
int& myFunction() { .... }
```

References behave almost like pointers. Your example though has some issues.

The object you allocate needs to be deleted at some point, and normally this is handled via pointers. Canonically, it's very weird to receive a reference that you need to later `delete`.

It's also not common in modern C++ to handle memory allocations in this disconnected way. I agree with your suggestion of returning a `shared_ptr`. This makes ownership explicit, and doesn't inadvertently leak memory like your example can.

Your example doesn't *necessarily* cause a memory leak, but it's awkward because you place certain requirements on the caller (namely, to `delete` the returned object) that are not enforced by the compiler.

---

Edit, to address the folks suggesting to return by value: it just depends on the requirements of the caller. Many small / utility objects like `Rectangle` or `Size` are meant to be passed around by value and this makes things very simple and intuitive.

A practical example of this would be something like:

```
inline Rect make_square_rect(int left, int right, int width)
{
  return Rect(left, right, width, width);
}
```

Definitely a function like this is best to return by value. Note how similar this functionality is to a constructor though...

For other bigger, more committed and stateful objects like `TcpConnection` or `Window`, this similarity becomes clearer. The question of ownership and memory management is amplified.

The same goes for anything that can't be copied/moved.

And thus, the creation of a new `Window` cannot be so casual as with a `Rect`. Creating a `Rect` from a function like yours just doesn't really care much about the question of ownership because of how cheap & simple it is to copy a `Rect` object. But if your function returns something like `Window`, then it's natural that your function would address ownership -- likely by returning a `shared_ptr<Window>`.

---

Edit #2: constructor nature

In response to your comments, I will point out again that these functions are *very* similar to constructors. These functions are really supposed to just set up an object for first use - but we're sitting here trying to decide how the function should handle ownership / copying.

Really, this is exactly what a constructor should do.

```
struct BigInteger
{
    BigInteger(int initial_value) { ... }
};
```

Here, the constructor doesn't need to deal with the concepts we're talking about. The caller decides how he wants to handle ownership:

```
BigInteger* ptr = new BigInteger(42);
BigInteger val = BigInteger(42);
```

Written as a constructor, this can handle both cases. The way I see it, the annoying thing about this situation is that constructors cannot be named in C++. For example, imagine you're writing these functions:

```
BigInteger make_big_integer_by_multiplying(int a, int b) { ... }
BigInteger make_big_integer_by_adding(int a, int b) { ... }
```

There's no good way to turn these into constructors. You need a symbol name to differentiate these functions, and constructors can't have names.

Written as a freestanding function, you're forced to decide on the ownership behavior. You have to just weigh the pros/cons, and mostly: consider how the callers want to use the object. If callers will want a persistent, stateful long-lived object, then return a `shared_ptr`. If callers will use the object as an intermediate, value type (which I'd argue `BigInteger` absolutely is) then return by value.

Comment: Your explanation was very enlightening. Thanks for the response. Actually, I am implementing a BigInteger class just as a practical exercise to learn more about best design decisions involved in C++. I am modeling the BigInteger as private vector<short> and was wondering the behavior I could get in extremes cases. Let's suppose a situation where is NEEDED to construct a copy, i.e. the pain of building the whole object from scratch is required. In this case, for the sake of simplicity maintain several values is preferred over several shared_ptr, right?

Comment: Also, given the optimization of return values that some folks mentioned above, is there a significant difference in performance even for larger objects when using return values or shared_ptr, provided that several copies are needed.

Comment: added more babbling in my answer :D And regarding performance, honestly I wouldn't even think about performance unless you identify something obviously problematic right away. Focus first on a clean, expressive code design, and deal with performance issues as they arise. And keep in mind that copies will all be in the caller's code. If the caller wants to avoid copies, then the caller should ... stop making unnecessary copies. It's irrelevant to writing this function.

Comment: As this discussion evolved, I really think now that returning references has very restrict use cases, probably the operator overloading signatures confused me a little bit and I started to apply this pattern where it doesn't make much sense at all.